# Find Full Weeks and Days between a Date Range using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My date range is

```
var currDay = Jan.1
var birthday = Feb.15
```

I know that to find the difference in number of weeks is

```
currDay.diff(birthday, 'week')
```

However, is there a way to find the full weeks and the remaining days?

Comment: The difference in weeks and days ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Yes, so how many full weeks and days would get to the current birthday

Comment: Get number of days then divide by 7?

Comment: @H77 I was thinking about that, I was hoping there was a way to do it in moment.js, since I might also have to find the diff in months, and each month has a different number of days.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [`duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

You can get the years, months (excludes years) and days (excludes years and months) using this. Only problem is weeks are calculated using the value of days so you'd still have to get the remainder on days if you're getting the number of weeks.

From [momentjs docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/weeks/):

> Pay attention that unlike the other getters for duration, weeks are
>   counted as a subset of the days, and are not taken off the days count.

Note: If you want the total number of weeks use `asWeeks()` instead of `weeks()`

```js
var currDay = moment("2018-01-01");
var birthday = moment("2018-02-16");

var diff = moment.duration(birthday.diff(currDay));

console.log(diff.months() + " months, " + diff.weeks() + " weeks, " + diff.days()%7 + " days.");

console.log(Math.floor(diff.asWeeks()) + " weeks, " + diff.days()%7 + " days.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currDay = moment("Jan.1","MMM.DD");
var birthday = moment("Feb.15","MMM.DD");

var diff = moment.duration(birthday.diff(currDay));

console.log(diff.weeks() +" weeks & "+ diff.days()%7 +" days to go for birthday");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```